# Assigning an Array from a Two-Dimensional Array - C#

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm not understanding why the following code is raising CS0022: Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2.

```
int[] oneArray; 
int[,] twoArray = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 3, 2, 1 } };

oneArray = twoArray[0];
```

I have declared an array and am unable to assign it to an array from my two-dimensional array.

Maybe I'm too used to Python...I'd appreciate any information on the topic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [Jagged Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) then your above code would work.

> A jagged array is an array whose elements are arrays, possibly of different sizes. A jagged array is sometimes called an "array of arrays."

A jagged array is typed using 2 sets of square brackets, eg. `int[][]`, where each entry is an array that can be directly accessed and assigned to/from your variable.

```
int[] oneArray;
int[][] jaggedArray = { new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new int[] { 3, 2, 1 } };

oneArray = jaggedArray[0];
jaggedArray[0] = oneArray;
```